# I'm wondering if the parts I have ordered to be vacuum casted and made have instead been made using 3D printing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, plastic, 3d-printing

The reason why I'm asking this in the first place is that I have observed striations on the parts I have received.

I was under the impression that vacuum casted parts would not have striations that mimic those of FDM or SLA processes.

Comment: How was the mold made? was the interior left with a poor surface or mirror smooth?

Comment: did you specify a surface finish for the mould?

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely common for vacuum forming moulds to be made with a 3D printed master part. If that master part wasn't hand-finished to a high standard to remove the layer lines, then these would be visible on your final parts.

**Visible layer lines are not evidence that the part has not been vacuum formed**.

The surface finish of the part, if critical, should have been specified to the supplier when placing your order.

Comment: the part does not even need to be 3D printed, it can also just be the stepover from the milling process. Indeed if you just send 3D models without other relevant specifications you get what you get.